# Split bootstrap's carousel slide in multiple slides next to each other and change visibility of arrows

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to do a `carousel` in bootstrap which is split into `187x300` slides but the slides to stay some sort of next each other with a little space between them.

Also, I have resized the carousel to the size of the slide but the only visible arrow is the left one and it's on the slide itself.

I would like it to be outside of it of some sort like to the left but outside of the slide (same for the right side).

I will attach an image as for example.

Also (I know I am repeating myself), if it's not too heavy for this question I would like it to do it like some sort of a Netflix carousel so on hover of the slide the image becomes a tiny bit bigger and it has a black overlay with text over the overlay. Thank you.

[image]

**Code :**

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Na merge</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css">


</head>

<body>

  <div class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <!--Slides-->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <!--First slide-->
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/187x300"
          alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <!--/First slide-->
      <!--Second slide-->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/187x300"
          alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <!--/Second slide-->
      <!--Third slide-->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/187x300"
          alt="Third slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/187x300"
          alt="Third slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/187x300"
          alt="Fourth slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/187x300"
          alt="Fifth slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/187x300"
          alt="Sixth slide">
      </div>
      <!--/Third slide-->
    </div>
    <!--/.Slides-->
    <!--Controls-->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#fullCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#fullCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    <!--/.Controls-->
  </div>
  <!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.carousel-item{
    height: 300px;
    width: 187px;
}
.carousel-item img{
  height: 300px;
  width: 187px;
}
```

Comment: Please share or snip your code.

Comment: @Arian Atapour please share your html code with respective css for better understanding.

Comment: Ok but its just a dummy so its not much of a code

Comment: @AminKarimi I have aded code now

Comment: If you want to scroll the items one at a time, the bootstrap carousel has no option for that. You will need to use a different plugin.

Comment: @Sirence Thank you for your answer, could I have an example of such a plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this style :

```
.carousel-item{
   height: 300px;
   width: 187px;
}
```

Then add your items into one item like this :

```
<div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <img src"...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <img src="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <img src="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <img src="...">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```